# TypeScript: Change type of element in JSON object

Tags: json, typescript

I have a JSON object coming from a Firebase (Firestore) query.

```
let json = [{
  "historical_data": {
    "created_by": "HKyUyCuVj0g12htOsAPmGCcffBq2",
    "created_at": {
      "seconds": 1606403054,
      "nanoseconds": 416000000
    }
  }
}];
```

I need to update the `created_at` value to a Firestore server timestamp.

Therefore I would iterate and update the respective field like this:

```
for (var i in json) {
  var item = json[i];
  item.historical_data.created_at = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

Although VS Code is giving me the following error message:

```
Type 'FieldValue' is missing the following properties from type '{ seconds: number; nanoseconds: number; }': "seconds", "nanoseconds"
```

I understand the error and why it's happening, so is there any way to update the JSON and change or cast the type of `created_at` to another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly cast the return type of `serverTimestamp` with the `as` keyword in typescript:

```js
interface CreateAt {
    seconds: number;
    nanoseconds: number;
}

for (var i in json) {
  var item = json[i];
  item.historical_data.created_at = 
    firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as CreateAt;
}
```